# Using json file as data source for chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts

I am attempting to include some json values in a bar chart. I have the json logging to the console but not sure how to include in the data property for the chart. Here is the source json...

> {time: "2016-07-03T21:29:57.987Z", temperature: 25.2, pressure: 98241, altitude: 259.98737254818553}

Thanks

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>WeatherPush</title>
    <script src="../dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <style>
    canvas {
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='d1' style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:0px; z-index:1">
      <canvas id='canvas' width='250' height='500'>
            Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
      </canvas>
  </div>
  <div id='d1' style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:300px; z-index:1">
      <canvas id='canvas2' width='250' height='500'>
            Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
      </canvas>
  </div>
  <div id='d1' style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:600px; z-index:1">
      <canvas id='canvas3' width='250' height='500'>
            Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
      </canvas>
  </div>

    <script>

    var jsonObjGraph;

    var getDataPromise = $.getJSON('../data.json', function(data) {
       jsonObjGraph = data;
       console.log(jsonObjGraph);
    });

    getDataPromise.done(function () {
      // done
    });

    getDataPromise.fail(function () {
      // fail;
    });

    var barChartData = {
        labels : ["Temperature"],
        datasets : [
            {
              label: 'Temperature',
                data : []
            }
        ]

    }

    var barChartData2 = {
        labels : ["Pressure"],
        datasets : [
            {
              label: 'Pressure',
                data : []
            }
        ]

    }

    var barChartData3 = {
        labels : ["Altitude"],
        datasets : [
            {
              label: 'Altitude',
                data : []
            }
        ]

    }

    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                      type: 'bar',
                      data: barChartData,
                      options: {
                          elements: {
                              rectangle: {
                                  backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                                  borderWidth: 2,
                                  borderColor: 'gray',
                              }
                          },
                          responsive: true,
                          legend: {
                              position: 'right',
                              display: false,
                          },
                          title: {
                              display: false,
                              text: 'Temperature'
                          }
                      }
                  });

        var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx2, {
                      type: 'bar',
                      data: barChartData2,
                      options: {
                          elements: {
                              rectangle: {
                                  backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                                  borderWidth: 2,
                                  borderColor: 'gray',
                              }
                          },
                          responsive: true,
                          legend: {
                              display: false,
                              position: 'right',
                          },
                          title: {
                              display: false,
                              text: 'Pressure'
                          }
                      }
                  });

        var ctx3 = document.getElementById("canvas3").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx3, {
                      type: 'bar',
                      data: barChartData3,
                      options: {
                          elements: {
                              rectangle: {
                                  backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                                  borderWidth: 2,
                                  borderColor: 'gray',
                              }
                          },
                          responsive: true,
                          legend: {
                              display: false,
                              position: 'right',
                          },
                          title: {
                              display: false,
                              text: 'Pressure'
                          }
                      }
                  });
    }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>WeatherPush</title>
    <script src="../dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <style>
    canvas {
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='d1' style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:0px; z-index:1">
      <canvas id='canvas' width='250' height='500'>
            Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
      </canvas>
  </div>
  <div id='d1' style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:300px; z-index:1">
      <canvas id='canvas2' width='250' height='500'>
            Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
      </canvas>
  </div>
  <div id='d1' style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:600px; z-index:1">
      <canvas id='canvas3' width='250' height='500'>
            Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
      </canvas>
  </div>

<button id="updateDataset">Update Datasets</button>

<script>

$.getJSON("data.json", function (data) {
  time = data.time
  temp = data.temperature
  press = data.pressure
  alt = data.altitude

  console.log(time)

  var barChartData = {
    labels: ["Temperature"],
    datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Temperature',
      data: [temp]
              }
    ]
  };

  var barChartData2 = {
      labels : ["Pressure"],
      datasets : [
          {
            label: 'Pressure',
            data : [press]
          }
      ]

  };

  var barChartData3 = {
      labels : ["Altitude"],
      datasets : [
          {
            label: 'Altitude',
            data : [alt]
          }
      ]

  };

  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

  window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartData,
                options: {
                    elements: {
                        rectangle: {
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            borderColor: 'gray',
                        }
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    legend: {
                        display: false,
                        position: 'right',
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: time
                    }
                }
              }
            );

            var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx2, {
                          type: 'bar',
                          data: barChartData2,
                          options: {
                              elements: {
                                  rectangle: {
                                      backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                                      borderWidth: 2,
                                      borderColor: 'gray',
                                  }
                              },
                              responsive: true,
                              legend: {
                                  display: false,
                                  position: 'right',
                              },
                              title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: time
                              }
                          }
                      });

            var ctx3 = document.getElementById("canvas3").getContext("2d");
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx3, {
                          type: 'bar',
                          data: barChartData3,
                          options: {
                              elements: {
                                  rectangle: {
                                      backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                                      borderWidth: 2,
                                      borderColor: 'gray',
                                  }
                              },
                              responsive: true,
                              legend: {
                                  display: false,
                                  position: 'right',
                              },
                              title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: time
                              }
                          }
                      });

})

</script>
</body>

</html>
```